# Conditional Logic on my form, One option will take you to next

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, logic, conditional-statements

So the actual scenario is...

I have a form on a page that needs some conditional logic.

form fields...

Then, I have a bunch of questions for my customer which would determine what (form) would be displayed or not.

(i.e) What type of Marketing list are you looking for?

(options) Saturated or Targeted

If they choose Saturated, Then Saturated  displays

If they choose Targeted, Then Targeted  displays

either one or the other, both forms cannot be displayed at the same time.

and so on...

one prompt leads you to the next.

I would greatly appreciate any help I could get on this

This is the code I have so far:

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
       $(document).ready(function() {
    var url = window.location.href;
    var option = url.match(/option=(.*)/);
    if (option !== null) {
        $(".link ." . option[1]).trigger('click');
    }

    $(".link").bind('click', function () {
        $('#intro-tekst').hide();
        $('.boxes').hide();
        $('.link').removeClass('selected');
        $(this).removeClass('link');
        $('#' + $(this).prop('class')).show();
        $(this).addClass('link selected');       
    });   
});
</script>

<body>


    <p>
        Who Do You Want to Mail to?
        <ul>
            <li><a href="javascript:void(0);" class="link business">Business</a></li>
            <li><a href="javascript:void(0);" class="link residents">Residents</a></li>
            <li><a href="javascript:void(0);" class="link have-list">Have a list?</a></li>
        </ul>
    </p>
    <div class="boxes hidden" id="business">
What Type of Business List Do You Want?
        <ul>
            <li><a href="javascript:void(0);" class="link saturation">Saturation</a></li>
            <li><a href="javascript:void(0);" class="link targeted">Targeted</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="boxes hidden" id="saturation">
Do You Want To: Mail to an Entire Zip Code or Mail to a Radius from an Address?
        <ul>
            <li><a href="javascript:void(0);" class="link zipcode">Zipcode</a></li>
            <li><a href="javascript:void(0);" class="link radius">Radius</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="boxes hidden" id="zipcode">
<form>
    <label for="fname1">First Name: </label>    
    <input type="text" id="fname1" value="" name="fname1"/>
    </form>
    </div>
    <div class="boxes hidden" id="radius">
<form>
    <label for="fname1">First Name: </label>    
    <input type="text" id="fname1" value="" name="fname1"/>
    </form>
    </div>
    <div class="boxes hidden" id="targeted">
<div id="intro-tekst">Do You Want To: Mail to an Entire Zip Code or Mail to a Radius from an Address?
        <ul>
            <li><a href="javascript:void(0);" class="link zipcode">Zipcode</a></li>
            <li><a href="javascript:void(0);" class="link radius">Radius</a></li>
        </ul></div> 
    </div>
    <div class="boxes hidden" id="zipcode">
<form>
    <label for="fname1">First Name: </label>    
    <input type="text" id="fname1" value="" name="fname1"/>
    </form>
    </div>
    <div class="boxes hidden" id="radius">
<form>
    <label for="fname1">First Name: </label>    
    <input type="text" id="fname1" value="" name="fname1"/>
    </form>
    </div>
    <div class="boxes hidden" id="residents">
    <div id="intro-tekst">What Type of Consumer List Do You Want?
        <ul>
            <li><a href="javascript:void(0);" class="link saturation">Saturation</a></li>
            <li><a href="javascript:void(0);" class="link targeted">Targeted</a></li>
        </ul></div> 
    </div>
    </div>
    <div class="boxes hidden" id="have-list">
    <form>
    <label for="fname1">First Name: </label>    
    <input type="text" id="fname1" value="" name="fname1"/>
    </form>
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: `on()` is preferred over `bind()` from jQuery 1.7 onwards : http://api.jquery.com/on/

Comment: Any comment on how I can adjust my code to perform the task? One question will take you to the next based on the option selected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This gets you most of the way there: http://jsfiddle.net/rym2g/

The only thing it doesn't do at the moment is close all the other panes when you choose something further up the list. That I leave to you. :)

```
<form>
    <ul class="form-nav">
        <li><a href="#a-1">AAA</a></li>
        <li><a href="#a-2">BBB</a></li>
    </ul>
</form>

<form class="hidden" id="a-1">
    <ul class="form-nav">
        <li><a href="#a-1-1">aaa</a></li>
        <li><a href="#a-1-2">bbb</a></li>
    </ul>
</form>

<form class="hidden" id="a-1-1">
    <p>A-1-1</p>
</form>

<form class="hidden" id="a-1-2">
    <p>A-1-2</p>
</form>

<form class="hidden" id="a-2">
    <ul class="form-nav">
        <li><a href="#a-2-1">111</a></li>
        <li><a href="#a-2-2">222</a></li>
    </ul>
</form>

<form class="hidden" id="a-2-1">
    <p>A-2-1</p>
</form>

<form class="hidden" id="a-2-2">
    <p>A-2-2</p>
</form>
```

And JavaScript:

```
$(document).on("click", "ul.form-nav a", function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var id = event.target.href.replace(/^[^#]+/, "");
    console.log("Going to: " + id);
    $(id).show().focus();
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, This looks great! Going to figure out the rest then post!